# Jscroll "loading" is stuck when there is no second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jscrollpane, infinite-scroll

I'm using jscroll on a results page and everything works great except one thing.
If the results have fewer results than the first page can contain, the `loading` gets stuck on the page.
Meaning, if there is no `next` href, the `loading` just stays there.
However, on searches that have more results than 1 page - the `loading` disappears when it gets to the end.

I did some research and it seems to have something to do with the `distroy` but couldn't seem to figure it out.
I should also add that the following message appears in the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   and the URL is:
>   http://localhost:8000/PAGENAME/**undefined**

My code for the Jscroll is:

```
 function inifniteScroll(){
   $(document).ready(function(){

      $('.results').jscroll({
        loadingHtml: '<h3 style="color:blue;">Loading...</h3>'
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you simply disable jscroll when a null value is returned for the href attribute? Can you show us more code (of your markup)?

Answer (score 0):

Well I actually found a workaround which is pretty simple.
I just count the amount of results.
If the results amount is under the full page amount, I just don't call the jquery function, If it's the full length, I call it.

Comment: Which jQuery function are you not calling? Your code to jscroll is in the Document.ready function?